# Wireless clients connected to the repeater not getting IP addresses from the DHCP server

Tags: networking, dhcp, router, wifi, repeater

I have a Mikrotik wifi router and an Asus wifi router configured as wireless repeater connected to the Mikrotik. The connection between Mikrotik and Asus is through wifi. Asus is getting IP address from Mikrotik DHCP server. The wifi clients connected to the Asus are not getting IP address from the Mikrotik DHCP server. If I set the IP address manually on the wifi client the internet works. I eliminated potential faulty hardware by testing with two Mikrotik routers and three Asus routers. Something is blocking the DHCP.
Asus is N18U model with very few configuration possibilities. The Mikrotik is a hAP ac2 with a lot configuration possibilities.
In the past I had a similar situation with an Ubiquiti AP and I couldn't even isolate the problem.

Do you have any ideas where can be the problem or at least how can I troubleshoot it?

Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: If the Asus router is connected to a hotspot or a non Mikrotik router the wireless clients getting IP from the DHCP.

Answer (score -2):

What if you try start from the scratch usin the "First Time Configuration" [document](https://help.mikrotik.com/docs/display/ROS/First+Time+Configuration) which describes how to set up the device from the ground up, keep in mind that they will ask you to clear away all defaults.

Otherwise you could open a support ticket [support ticket](https://mikrotik.com/support) with MikroTik regarding this specific issue.

I hope you find this information helpful.